# Regular expression value update

Tags: c#, regex

I had written the below regular expression

```
string validnumber = @"^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}(?:-[0-9]{5})?$";
```

This will allow the numbers like "AA1234567" and "AA1234567-12345".

I want to allow below all formats

```
AA1234567?
AA1234567??
AA1234567???
AA1234567????

AA1234567-?
AA1234567-??
AA1234567-???
AA1234567-????
```

Can anyone please help me how can i write that

Comment: make the `-` optional, then

Comment: why now a days, there are too many negative votes on the question, too early? And it happens too early, not even allowing the op to find and fix the question!

Comment: Most of the time it's because they put little to no effort in creating their question, or at least that's what I have observed in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{7}(?:-?\d{1,4})?$
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/DffZNA/7)

Updated as per the comments

Comment: This is not throwing any error if i type the below type also BB5415852-1234514545

Comment: In the above expression d{1,4} will allow only numeric i want to allow alphanumeric character. what changes we need to do ?

Comment: I was tried this [a-zA-Z]{2}\d{7}(-?\[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4})?$ but this is not working as intended.

Comment: I have updated the Link in my answer plz have a look, let me know if it works

Comment: it was not allowing the alphabets + numberic combination values ex AA1234567aa12 , AA1234567-aa12

Answer (score 4):

I think this should work:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{7}(?:-?\d{1,4})?$
```

[Proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5ba-zA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%5cd%7b7%7d%28%3f%3a-%3f%5cd%7b1%2c4%7d%29%3f%24&i=AA1234567-122).

**Description:**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a question mark after the dash in the second sub-expression to make `'-'` character *optional*, and allow for the suffix to be from one to four digits long:

```
string validnumber = @"^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}(?:-?[0-9]{1,4})$";
//                                             ^      ^^^  ^
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/Cwyy8f/2)